# Process hollowing and the Import Address Table

Tags: injection, memory, c, process, code-execution

I have been learning and implementing Process Hollowing attacks, and even after I got the thing work, I have some questions.

1. Why aren't we building the IAT when we load our injected PE? All we do is copy the headers and the sections, fix reallocations (if there is a need in some) but never touching the IAT. I don't understand why it works.
2. In case we UnMap the victim process from its image base, suppose `0x40000`, we can't allocate this base address again, we get `INVALID_ADDRESS` error. This works with any other address, or in cases which the two image bases differ. I found a mention in some blog but no explanation.

- The malicious exe is dynamically linked and does not use bound imports as you may think
- Other checks that I performed:

  - If I debug the victim process along the way, I get an access violation because of the not build IAT (sound reasonable)
  - If I debug the program after the injection happened successfully, the IAT is built and the malicious exe runs without problems.

I assume that there is some code that I'm missing that builds the IAT at runtime, or it's something that happens from the OS scope.